# JS + Google Maps API v2

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

Есть такая непонятная штука: 
Вот скрипт:

```
function buildMap(lat,lon,level) {

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lon), level);
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
 }
```

Собственно - задача в том, чтобы объект **var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));**
то есть "map" была глобальной и могла вызываться с любой функции в скрипте.

Попытался сделать так:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));

function buildMap(lat,lon,level) {

    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lon), level);
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
 }
```

Но тогда возникает проблема в том, что при вызове функции "buildMap()" эта переменная не видна.... и хоть расшибись в столб головой. Не хочет работать и все тут.

После чего я решил проверить свой мозг на правильность суждений. Составил простенький скрипт:

```
var test = "123";

function show_test(){
     alert(test);
}
```

По итогу я вижу в Алерте значение переменной "test". Т.е. это доказывает что в данном случае переменная не пустая => "var map = ..." за пределами функции тоже должна была нормально проинициализироваться в функции и нормально в ней отработать.

Вопрос !!!!

Что за прикол ?:)

Comment: Проверьте alert(map.nodeName) до вашего кода. Если отзовется, переименуйте html-элемент map в, например, map_container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился сам- собой :)))

Причина была в том, что "buildMap" вызывалась уже после полной загрузки <body> в котором содержится div с id="map".

решено было так:

```
var map; function buildMap(){ map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map")); и т.д.....}
```

И ровненько после билда карты у меня появлялся в map-е ГЛОБАЛЬНО !! мой экземплярчик :)

Простите, пойду спать... давно я так не тупил )